# I'd appreciate it if + <past tense> + until + <present or past tense?>

Tags: backshifting

These three examples have the same construction of

> I'd appreciate it if you + past tense verb + ... + until + subject + present or past tense verb...

The first one has the present tense verb *finish* after *until* whereas the other two have the past tense verbs *got* and *were*:

From the movie 'Kingsman' ([video clip](https://youtu.be/HDJEyqNw-9k?t=105)):

> (1) Listen boys, I’ve had a rather emotional day. So whatever your beef with Eggsy is, I’d appreciate it enormously if you could leave us in peace until I **finish** this lovely pint of Guinness.

From the book "[The Ultimate Plan: A Financial Survival Guide for Life's Unexpected Events](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=uClQYa2idZsC&pg=PA33&dq=%22if%20you%20must%20have%20an%20attack,%20I%27d%20appreciate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qjj9VPiwGaXTmgXkh4H4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22if%20you%20must%20have%20an%20attack%2C%20I'd%20appreciate%22&f=false)":

> (2) So if you must have an attack, I'd appreciate it if you could wait until we **got** to Broadway.

From the book "[Touching Darkness: Number 2 in series](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=03NObIQgij0C&pg=PT89&dq=%22appreciate%20it%20if%20you%20waited%20until%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6D_VP7fCaPMmwX_gIH4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22appreciate%20it%20if%20you%20waited%20until%22&f=false)":

> (3) 'Still, Melissa,' he said, 'this *is* a classroom, and I'd appreciate it if you waited until you **were** out in the hall before turning that thing on.'

Note that all the verbs after *until* (***finish***, ***got***, and ***were***) describe a future situation.

Can you have the past tense verb ***finished*** in (1)?

Also, can you have the present tense verbs ***get*** and ***are*** in (2) and (3), respectively?

Is there a rule that determines the tense of the verbs after *until*?

Comment: I don't think this is backshifting in the usual sense. More like a way of edging *can* and *wait* towards an irrealis meaning.

Comment: Yes, that's what I took you to mean by it in the question (because otherwise *backshifting* is not a 'reason', just a redescription of what you've observed).

Comment: It may be the right term, I don't know - I was just explaining what I'd assumed you meant. I find *I'd appreciate it if you wait* marginal. *I'd appreciate it if you'd wait* and *I'd appreciate it if you waited* are fine for me, and are equivalent. It's the same for the modal verbs really. I think it's the *would* after *appreciate* requiring what follows to be marked as something that is merely envisaged. *I'd appreciate it if you were to wait* does not sound wrong to me exactly, but it does sound stilted.

Comment: @JK2 sorry, I hadn't read it properly. I'd say that *until* is normally followed by a verb in the present or present perfect (when it relates to a future time) and what licenses the past tenses in (2) and (3) is *could* and *waited*. For me, the past tense is not required in either case, and to use it implies a counterfactual. That said, if it is not a counterfactual I would put the previous verb in the present tense or use modal + infinitive, as in (1).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149011/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-id-appreciate-it-if-past-tense-until-pre); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you have the past tense verb finished in (1)?**

Yes, but usually you would add the word "have."

Listen boys, I’ve had a rather emotional day. So whatever your beef with Eggsy is, I’d appreciate it enormously if you could leave us in peace until I have finished this lovely pint of Guinness.

**Also, can you have the present tense verbs get and are in (2) and (3), respectively?**

Yes, you can.  No modification needed, it is the same.

So if you must have an attack, I'd appreciate it if you could wait until we get to Broadway.

'Still, Melissa,' he said, 'this is a classroom, and I'd appreciate it if you waited until you are out in the hall before turning that thing on.'